# IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5 Express URL Routing issue

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-routing, webforms

Update:

I change the Question Title and try to make the environment clearly to explain my question!

and Important: Thank you for your help, sincerely!

Pic1: Remote IIS 7.0: you can see the code and website structure!
[image: Remote IIS 7.0: you can see the code and website structure!]
Pic2: Remote IIS 7.0: you can see the Url redirect just can't run!
[image: Remote IIS 7.0: you can see the Url redirect just can't run!]
Pic3: Locally IIS 7.5 Express: I copy all of the code to my VS2010 and its show the folder information on picture!
[image: Locally IIS 7.5 Express: I copy all of the code to my VS2010 and its show the folder information on picture!]
Pic4: Locally IIS 7.5 Express: When I click play button, it runs perfect!? what's wrong?
[image: Locally IIS 7.5 Express: When I click play button, it runs perfect!? what's wrong?]

Full size picture download: [picture download](https://sites.google.com/site/slashtsai/home/IIS.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

Full size picture download(2, new post): [picture download](https://sites.google.com/site/slashtsai/home/IIS2.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: Great update, could you please add another image for current IIS application pools, and another for current website application pool setting, and run the following command in visual studio command prompt and add results here "aspnet_regiis -lv"... do these on remote server(where IIS7 resides) thanks for good information

Comment: hi Beygi, i've upload new picture zip files and update download link. plz take a look, thank you! ^^

Comment: in information that you provided every thing seems to be fine..., now this question have about 60 viewer which is a prove that you did all well, the only thing that you can do now is to re-register asp.net in IIS7 using aspnet_regiis -i in visual studio command prompt, make sure you have installed the .net framework full version and also upload the web.config file to be revised if necessary... other than that you may need to re-install windows, after installing IIS(updating it to 7.5 if possible) installing asp.net and .net framework...

Comment: OK! I'll try to reinstall Windows, and thank you very much! :)

Comment: Sorry if i couldn't help you without reinstalling windows, but please, add updates here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Make sure your website is running in IntegratedMode and it's better
    to use Asp.Net 4 Application pool (not the classic one).

2.Make sure that you have routing configured in web.config or modify
    it like this

```
<system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/> 
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
    </modules> 
    <handlers> 
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/> 
    </handlers> 
</system.webServer>
```

3.Make sure that you have installed the HTTP Redirection feature

> Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn windows features on or
>   off > IIS > World wide web Services > Common HTTP Features > HTTP
>   Redirection

4.Make sure that you have Global.asax file in the root of your website(IIS7 remote server, not in Visual Studio), or it will not executed. Also keep your logic in the Global.asax file as plain text, don't rely on the compiled dll version App_global.asax.dll.

> **Note:** Some how make sure that the global.asax code is executing on the remote server
>   if you could add a breakpoint for example that will do it

5.Try reaching the page using its real location like 127.0.0.1/test.aspx, to see if your website is up and running without any problem(on IIS7 remote server).

6.If you're reaching a page using its physical location like this 127.0.0.1/test.aspx then your routing configuration should look like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "test-route-sample",
    "home/test-route",
    "~/test.aspx"
)
```

You can access this page with its new routing location using this url

> 127.0.0.1/home/test-route

Comment: yes, I check my pipeline mode is showing Integrated! but still can't work.

Comment: 1. I'm sure that all use Framework 4.0, and now only different is IIS 7.0 (remote; can't run) and IIS 7.5 Express(locally; can run).

2. I perform three steps that you means and nothing make it works.

3. I am not use MVC but web-form structure.

4. Any idea for set Virtual Directory "Root" up? I can feel the bug is oriented to ASP.NET can't point to right path when execute code "~/BBB/CCC.aspx", even I change .asax inside-code to "~/test.aspx" and put real files in "<iisroot>/test.aspx".

Comment: Beygi, Very very thanks for your help! and hope your suggestion can solve my bug! ^^

Answer (score 0):

What is your virtual directory root in IIS? If it is BBB (rather than at the root) then requests under AAA won't reach your application to be routed.

Comment: In IIS 7, my root directory directly point to \\x.x.x.x\, so BBB is the 1st level folder in my IIS. In IIS Express, I copy all code to a physical disk, and root directory point to a normal folder, like "d:\site". And in this folder BBB still the 1st level folder in my IIS. I don't change any code but it works!?